# how can I select data from MySQL based on date (unix time record)

Tags: php, mysql, unix, date, time

I have a record of data with unix time date in it

i want to select the row based on the date/month/year only (not with time)

currently Im using something like this

```
select * 
  from tablename 
 where date > '$today' 
   and date < '$tomorow' 
 LIMIT 1;
```

how ever this is not that accurate if the $today and $tomorrow have different time (but same date)

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: why do people delete their answer, I cant say thank you to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) > DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('$today')) ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: This would cause the query to use a table scan, which may not be desirable if the table is very large.

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement :

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE LIKE 'YEAR-MOTH-DATE%'.
```

For example I use this for my case:

```
 SELECT * FROM USER_MANAGER u WHERE DATE_REGISTER LIKE '2012-09-08%';
```